# For B-spline what does $\sum_{i=0,n}N_{i,k}(t)=1$ mean?

Tags: splines

For B-spline what does $\sum_{i=0,n}N_{i,k}(t)=1$ mean?

I don't understand what this means cause $N_{i,k}(t)$ are basis functions so what does it mean for them to all sum up to 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That means that all the B-Spline basis functions sum to 1 **at every $t$.**

Without that constraint, any scaling of valid basis functions would give a new, valid set of basis functions that could represent a spline, but with different coefficients.